# Docker Run Failed Due to --log-opts

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-run

I am running a docker run command to spawn a new container. The command I gave:

```
docker run -h 'activemq1' --net bridge -m 20g --env-file /opt/dockerenv/activemq-1/env.txt -p 8161:8161 -p 61613:61613 -p 61614:61614 -p 61616:61616 -p 1616:1616 -p 5672:5672 -p 1883:1883 -v /opt/dckexchange:/exchange -v /etc/yum.repos.d:/etc/yum.repos.d -v /mnt/data/volumes/activemq1/data:/usr/share/activemq/data --log-opt max-size=1g --log-opt max-file=2 --name activemq-dev mydocker:5000/activemq/activemq:latest
```

It should be running perfectly without error, but apparently it throws me an error unknown flag: --log-opts. It is running ok if I remove all of the log-opt command.

Docker version: 1.13.1

Any ideas?

Comment: it called `--log-opt` without the `s` at end

Comment: @LinPy yea, sorry I was typo in the question. It shouldn't be having 's' at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're missing the log-driver e.g.

```
--log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=1g --log-opt max-file=2
```

I think you need this unless you've specified a default in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Comment: Thanks @Ryan.Bartsch. Yes I do realize it. But apparently on the other server, with (older) docker version <1.8.2>, the command runs successfully. I will accept your answer as the correct one.